# What does disabling/enabling Windows Aero extensions do?

Tags: team-fortress-2

[image]

See the bottom right option, under DirectX? I still haven't figured out what it does, and changing the setting and clicking OK yields no visual change.

Is disabling it critical to any game fucntions (!MOTD, etc)?  Does disabling yield a performance boost? In any case, what does that option do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling it should have no functional impact to your game but it may improve your FPS slightly, I believe it is only active if you play in "Windowed mode" - it just makes things like the taskbar all pretty.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the [SteamDB tracker](https://github.com/SteamDatabase/GameTracking-TF2/blob/master/hl2/resource/gameui_english.txt), the option *should* control whether [D3D9Ex (Direct3D 9Ex)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/direct3d-9ex-improvements) is used or not (the variable `mat_disable_d3d9ex` gets toggled under the hood). It was introduced somewhen [by](https://store.steampowered.com/oldnews/7024) 2011, and it became enabled by default in [June](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=16010) of the following year.

It's no longer there though (since late 2015 [probably](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Template:PatchDiff/December_17,_2015_Patch/hl2/resource/optionssubvideoadvanceddlg.res)?), and it's enabled by default. The `-nod3d9ex` parameter should still allow you to get back to vanilla D3D9.

Comment: This answer is... very technical. Could be better if you explained what that D3D9Ex thing did. Because right now when reading it if feels like you are pointing at a light switch, but we have no idea what the hell that light switch does

Comment: Thing is, I don't really know what specific [features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee890072(v=vs.85).aspx) they used either. I can only see they didn't switch to `D3DSWAPEFFECT_FLIPEX`, while presumably doing *something* for [memory](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/December_17,_2015_Patch#Performance_Improvements)/[cpu](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2019/03/23362/). Even if I look at the leaked source code [this](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d9/nf-d3d9-idirect3ddevice9-createtexture#remarks) seemed the only associated adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

Turns of all the nice looking Windows Vista/7 features while playing, saving up a few resources. Can be done also by simply right clicking hl2.exe and checking a few boxes. Overall making your fps higher.